# combine coding between indy and ics

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

i have been using Indy for a while , and now i am trying to work around with another internet component like **ICS** and combine Indy code to have same approach in **ICS** i started by creating `TWSocketserver` and start communicate with client `Twsocket` iam stuck with one thing , in indy `TIDTCPSERVER` i usually use `AContext` to define each client connect on server connect event  as example

```
TConnection = class(TObject)

    Thread: Pointer;
    end;

    var
      Connection : TConnection;
    begin
    Connection := TConnection.Create;
    Connection.Thread := AContext;
    AContext.Data := Connection;
    end;
```

but in `TwSocketserver` is different parameters .

my question is can combine the code Above with **ICS** to have the same approach  ?

---

**things i have tried**

```
procedure Tmainserver.serverClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Client: TWSocketClient; Error: Word);
var
Connection : TConnection;
begin
Connection := TConnection.Create;
Connection.Thread := Client;
end;
```

but is Client: TWSocketClient; have tobject class to be identified  ?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  What EXACTLY are you trying to combine?  Please narrow it down.  What are you having a problem with?  What do you WANT to do that you are not ABLE to do?  I *think* what you are trying to ask is how to track data on a per-client basis in `TWSocketServer` similar to how you do it in TIdTCPServer`, is that right? Please clarify your question.

Comment: yes thats exactly the question , in indy tcp i can set pointer with `Acontext` then set `Acontext.data` with client information who just connect. to be able  to identify each client who connected  . as example client a - client B - client C

Comment: You can derive a custom class from `TWSocketClient` and assign it to the `TWSocketServer.ClientClass` property, then you can add whatever you want to that class, and access it by typecasting `TClient` objects when needed, such as in the `OnClientCreate` and `OnClientConnect` events. Indy also has a similar feature, where you can assign a custom `TIdServerContext`-derived class to the `TIdTCPServer.ContextClass` property, and then typecast `TIdContext` objects when needed, such as in the `OnConnect` and `OnExecute` events.  I prefer this approach instead of using the `TIdContext.Data` property.

Comment: i updated of what i try its seems `Client: TWSocketClient ` dont have the same ability to assign client data with his  pointer as `TIdContext.Data` as example there is no `Client.data` inside ics

Comment: You missed the point I was trying to make. You don't *need* a `Data` property since the Client object *itself* is a custom object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can derive a custom class from `TWSocketClient` and assign it to the `TWSocketServer.ClientClass` property before calling `TWSocketServer.Listen()`, then you can add whatever you want to your class, and access your custom fields/methods by typecasting a `TWSocketClient` object when needed, such as in the `TWSocketServer.OnClientCreate` and `TWSocketServer.OnClientConnect` events.  There is an example of that demonstrated in the following EDN article:

[Writing Client/Server applications using ICS](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20465)

In your case, try something like this:

```
type
  TConnection = class
    Client: Pointer;
  end;

  TMyClient = class(TWSocketClient)
  public
    Connection: TConnection;
  end;

procedure Tmainserver.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  server.ClientClass := TMyClient;
end;

procedure Tmainserver.serverClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Client: TWSocketClient; Error: Word);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  Connection := TConnection.Create;
  Connection.Client := Client;
  TMyClient(Client).Connection := Connection;
end;

procedure Tmainserver.serverClientDisconnect(Sender : TObject;
  Client : TWSocketClient; Error  : Word); 
begin
  FreeAndNil(TMyClient(Client).Connection);
end;
```

FYI, Indy has a similar feature.  You assign a custom `TIdServerContext`-derived class to the `TIdTCPServer.ContextClass` property before activating the server, and then typecast `TIdContext` objects when needed, such as in the `TIdTCPServer.OnConnect` and `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` events:

```
type
  TConnection = class
    Context: Pointer;
  end;

  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    // TIdContext already has a property named 'Connection'...
    MyConnection: TConnection;
  end;

procedure Tmainserver.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  server.ContextClass := TMyContext;
end;

procedure Tmainserver.serverConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  Connection := TConnection.Create;
  Connection.Context := AContext;
  TMyContext(AContext).MyConnection := Connection;
end;

procedure Tmainserver.serverDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext); 
begin
  FreeAndNil(TMyContext(AContext).MyConnection);
end;
```

I prefer this approach instead of using the `TIdContext.Data` property.